# openGL not drawing mesh when I pass parameters to a function to draw

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

so I'm an openGL beginner and am attempting to draw 'Bones' recursively.

I can draw my mesh fine within my 'do' loop however when I try to pass the 'Bone' object to a function to draw the mesh it doesn't draw?

```
void drawBone(Bone &bone, mat4 ProjectionMatrix, mat4 ViewMatrix)
{
    ModelMatrix = bone.getBoneModel();
    MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
}
```

If I paste those 4 lines back into my 'do' loop in place of 'drawBone()' the mesh draws just fine.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Are your matrices copy constructors working as expected, since you are passing them by value? And where does that MatrixID come from, it appears to be something defined outside that function, but it's not one of the parameters?

Comment: Yeah, I think you have a few programming errors here. Do you get any errors when compiling? Also, where is `vertices` defined?

Comment: Do you Call glUseProgram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few global variables like `MatrixID` and `vertices`. 
make sure these are globally accessible and you are not redeclaring them within your "do" loop

Comment: Thank you! Yes I had changed vertices and MatrixID to be global variables but also left them declared within the main(). Commenting out the second declarations fixed it!